# Mobile browsers are adding .html to filename on download

Tags: php, file, mobile, file-extension, vcf-vcard

For some reason, with this code:

```
header("Content-Type: text/x-vcard;charset=utf-8;");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=card.vcf");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo $vcard_serialized;
```

on chrome from Pc, it downloads `card.vcf`, but from mobile it downloads `card.vcf.html`... why?

Comment: Is there any accidental HTML content in the output?

Comment: @ADyson no, only vcf content... I see similar answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363744/safari-adding-html-to-download but if I use this, Safari tells me "Safari can't download this file"

Comment: That link seems to be a link back to this question...

Comment: @ADyson my bad, edited

Comment: So you mean Safari complains if you use `exit;` at the end?

Comment: @ADyson yes, with the terminal `exit`, safari says that

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but now I already fixed it using the codes below:

```
header('Content-Description: Download vCard');
header('Content-Type: text/vcard');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$your_filename_here);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $vcard_serialized; //echo the content
exit;
```